# SQL Server Query in PowerShell, limit my results based on date

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using PowerShell to connect to a SQL Server database, and I want to limit my result.

I use the SqlServer Module, and Invoke-Sqlcmd. I don't want data where the date is older than 90 days. The following code is used to get the complete data

```
$DataRange = ((Get-date) + (New-TimeSpan -Days -90))
$Database = DB02_Tool.dbo.Cert
$ServerInstans = DBClu01\DbClu01Cert
$Query = "SELECT encoded, not_before, not_after FROM " + $Database
$Data = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstans -Query $Query -As DataRows
```

The limit, I want to implement is on the not_before, which is of the datatype datetime, and I want it to limit on dates not older than 90 days back, as the  $Daterange is used for.How do I limit the query? Any ideas?

Comment: So simple,  thanks a lot :) That saved my day (And game some insight to sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the SQL Query. Using `DATEADD` to add or substract days, and `GetDate()` to get the current datetime.

```
$Query = "SELECT encoded, not_before, not_after FROM " + $Database + " WHERE not_before >= DATEADD(Day, -90, GetDate())"
```

Or you can pass in a parameter from Powershell using `-Variable` switch. See the [example 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#examples) in the documentation.

*You first need to convert the string to a universal datetime using ToString("u")*

```
$StringArray = "MYVAR1='$($DataRange.ToString("u"))'"
$Query = "SELECT encoded, not_before, not_after FROM " + $Database  + " WHERE not_before >= `$(MYVAR1)"

$Data = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstans -Query $Query -Variable $StringArray -As DataRows
```

Comment: So simple, thanks a lot :) That saved my day (And game some insight to sql)